# Looking for a tool that can traceback an outgoing connection

Tags: linux, monitoring

I've noticed some outgoing connections from my server to IP's that look
suspicious to me. Is there any tool that can catch this outgoing ping/connection and tells me the programm on my system that initiated that process?

OS: Linux / openSUSE

Comment: Have you tried `netstat -p`?

Comment: Could work, but firewall drops it, in this case its not listed

Comment: Maybe watching `iftop`? Or does that run into the same firewall issue?

Comment: What about looking in firewall logs?